# Mixed Content Error when testing via Cypress

Tags: javascript, html, cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to test a player loaded by the webpage I currently test.

When testing manually everything works as expected and via https.
But when I run my cypress test the player is not loading and I get a `Mixed Content`-Error because it seems to request resources via http. Therefore the player is not loading.

[image: Screenshot of browser console errors]

I already tried adding a `upgrade-insecure-requests : 1` header to every request and setting `chromeWebSecurity : false` in the config but neither seems to work.

EDIT:
After some further research I found the html script tags requesting the sources. Their URLs start with `//` which cypress seems to use http for instead of the protocol used beforehand (https).[image]

Has someone already experienced this or found a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can avoid this error by setting   "chromeWebSecurity" to false in your cypress config file. 
`cypress.config.json`

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // ...
    },
  },
  "chromeWebSecurity": false //add this param to your config file
});
```